# Spark configuration for Out of memory error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Cluster setup -

```
Driver has 28gb
Workers have 56gb each (8 workers)
```

Configuration -

```
spark.memory.offHeap.enabled true
spark.driver.memory 20g
spark.memory.offHeap.size 16gb
spark.executor.memory 40g
```

My job -

```
//myFunc just takes a string s and does some transformations on it, they are very small strings, but there's about 10million to process.


//Out of memory failure
data.map(s => myFunc(s)).saveAsTextFile(outFile)

//works fine
data.map(s => myFunc(s))
```

Also, I de-clustered / removed spark from my program and it completed just fine(successfully saved to a file) on a single server with 56gb of ram.  This shows that it just a spark configuration issue.  I reviewed https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management and the configurations I currently have seem to be all that should be needed to be changed for my job to work.  What else should I be changing?

Update -

Data -

```
val fis: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFile))
val bis: BufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
val input: CompressorInputStream = new CompressorStreamFactory().createCompressorInputStream(bis);
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))
val stringArray = br.lines().toArray()
val data = sc.parallelize(stringArray)
```

Note - this does not cause any memory issues, even though it is incredibly inefficient.  I can't read from it using spark because it throws some EOF errors.

myFunc, I can't really post the code for it because it's complex.  But basically, the input string is a deliminated string, it does some deliminator replacement, date/time normalizing and things like that.  The output string will be roughly the same size as an input string.

Also, it works fine for smaller data sizes, and the output is correct and roughly the same size as input data file, as it should be.

Comment: What is `data` and how is it generated?  what is the definition of `myFunc`?  There could be something causing memory problems within `myFunc`, but more likely the problem is one of the other transformations used to create `data`. It's impossible to tell without seeing the code.  So we need to see the full flow from source file.  The one that works fine does so because it doesn't do anything.  Remember nothing happens in spark until you run an action.

Comment: @puhlen updated main post with information

Answer (score 0):

Would help if you put more details of what going on in your program before and after the MAP. 
Second command (only Map) does not do anything unless an action is triggered. Your file is probably not partitioned and driver is doing the work. Below should force data to workers evenly and protect OOM on a single node. It will cause shuffling of data though.

Updating solution after looking at your code, will be better if you do this

```
val data = sc.parallelize(stringArray).repartition(8)
data.map(s => myFunc(s)).saveAsTextFile(outFile)
```

Comment: I added an update to my post with some more information.  I will try that though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You current solution does not take advantage of spark.  You are loading the entire file into an array in memory, then using sc.parallelize to distribute it into an RDD.  This is hugely wasteful of memory (even without spark) and will of course cause out of memory problems for large files.

Instead, use `sc.textFile(filePath)` to create your RDD.  Then spark is able to smartly read and process the file in chunks, so only a small portion of it needs to be in memory at a time.  You are also able to take advantage of parallelism this way, as spark will be able to read and process the file in parallel, with however many executors and corse your have, instead of needing the read the entire file on a single thread on a single machine.

Assuming that myFunc can look at only a single line at a time, then this program should have a very small memory footprint.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, I put a note saying that this was not possible because I get some EOF errors and the input files cannot be modified in anyway.  But would this fix my issue if I somehow got this to work? Since reading the entire file does not cause a memory error in and of itself.

Comment: Also yes, `MyFunc` only takes in one line at a time and there are 15million~ lines

Comment: @jayjay93 Yes if you got it to work using `textfile` it should solve your problem.  You could also increase the driver memory if you feel you need to load a large dataset into an array then use `sc.parallelize`.  If the program works fine without spark though, then why not just do that.  You could probably write an efficient program that uses under 100MB of ram running on a single machine to do the task based on your description.

Comment: I am not doubting you but before I try and fix the textfile issue, I can store the entire file on my driver while only using 20% of the memory.  So why would "smart reading" the file help me from running out of memory?The 15million item array on the driver is not causing any issues at all, I have tested that.

Comment: .///////////////

Comment: @jayjay93  parallelizing the array ends up using much more memory than just having a regular array, so while it might fit on it's own it can still be too big for parallelize.  If you have to do it this way, and you can't just give the driver more memory, perhaps you could chunk the operation somehow by loading only parts of the file at a time.